# Count columns and sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to the SQL, and I have a table with id (question id) and risk areas (risk1, risk2, and risk3).

```
+----+-------+------+------+
| id | risk1 | risk2| risk3|
+----+-------+------+------+
| 0  |   h   |   l  |   h  |
| 1  |   m   |   l  |   l  |
| 2  |   h   |   h  |   h  |
| 3  |   l   |   l  |   h  |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

My aim is to calculate the sum of 'h' for individual ids. For example the query should return '2' for id=0, '0' for id=1, '3' for id=2, and '1' for id=3. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Seriously consider amending your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [verbose] query is:

```
select
  id,
  case when risk1 = 'h' then 1 end +
  case when risk2 = 'h' then 1 end +
  case when risk3 = 'h' then 1 end as sum_h
from t
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
SELECT
    id,
    IF(COALESCE(risk1, '') = 'h', 1, 0) +
    IF(COALESCE(risk2, '') = 'h', 1, 0) +
    IF(COALESCE(risk3, '') = 'h', 1, 0) AS h_sum
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

Just for fun, here is more exotic way of doing this, using string manipulation:

```
SELECT
    id,
    3 - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(risk1, risk2, risk3), 'h', '')) AS h_sum
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

[image]

### Demo

To make the second approach also be `NULL` safe, just use `COALESCE(risk1, '')` in place of `risk1` (and the same for the other columns).

Comment: I was answering something so similar to the second one XD

Comment: Moving a step ahead, how to avoid 'NULL'  in this calculation?

Comment: @ABS2019 Just use `COALESCE(risk1, '')` in place of `risk1`, and the same for the other columns.  Most of the answers given here already would work with just this change.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers, so this is easy to express:

```
select id,
       ( (risk1 = 'h') + (risk2 = 'h') + (risk3 = 'h') ) as num_hs
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that none of the values are `NULL` which appears to be the case with your data.

Answer (score 1):

A more conventional (we could say 'better') solution might be as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,risk_no INT NOT NULL
,risk_type CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,risk_no)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,'h'),
(2,1,'m'),
(3,1,'h'),
(4,1,'l'),

(1,2,'l'),
(2,2,'l'),
(3,2,'h'),
(4,2,'l'),

(1,3,'h'),
(2,3,'l'),
(3,3,'h'),
(4,3,'h');

SELECT id, COUNT(*) total FROM my_table WHERE risk_type = 'h' GROUP BY id;
+----+-------+
| id | total |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     2 |
|  3 |     3 |
|  4 |     1 |
+----+-------+
```

or

```
SELECT id, SUM(risk_type = 'h') total FROM my_table GROUP BY id;
+----+-------+
| id | total |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     2 |
|  2 |     0 |
|  3 |     3 |
|  4 |     1 |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: This is the way to go, but only assuming the OP has the liberty of changing his design (he may not).